# Deleted by X where X is the author - bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers

I was viewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359600/what-purpose-does-a-script-tag-serve-inside-of-a-noscript-tag?newsletter=1&nlcode=240525%7ccffe) and noticed a pair of deleted answers. One of them has the annotation "deleted by owner 2 days ago."  The other, by Wishy, has the annotation "deleted by Wishy yesterday." If you mouse over the username links, it is clear that Wishy the author and Wishy who deleted the post are one and the same.

[image]

This seems like an obvious bug.

Comment: I wonder if there was another delete vote first on Wishy's answer.

Comment: Bug report on MSE: [“Deleted by {owner}” vs “Deleted by owner” in self deleted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193771/213963)

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks. Travis J's comment on that post seems likely to be the answer, but there are no answers posted. This seems like there must be a definitive answer that someone could give.

Comment: @EdCottrell Probably not. In your example, the 153 reputation user does not have "sufficient criteria" assuming that means the ability to delete other posts.

Comment: @Anonymous good point; I misread that comment the first time around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks; this should be fixed now.