# Standardize the "deleted by" formatting on questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

When visiting an owner-deleted **question**, we get:

> **deleted** by [Username](https://www.google.com) 3 mins ago

but when viewing an owner-deleted **answer**, we get:

> deleted by owner Oct 11 '12 at 8:34

I personally prefer "delete by owner" since it doesn't force me to verify if the user id of the deleter is the same as the poster since usernames are not unique.

I've found:

- [Deleted by X where X is the author - bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269369/2191572)
- ["Deleted by {owner}" vs "Deleted by owner" in self deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193771/235923)
- [Why questions deleted by owner are not marked as "deleted by owner"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161821/235923)
- [Self-deleted posts by deleted users don't show "deleted by owner"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122832/235923)

but they claim to fix the issue even though it still seems to be an issue.

Am I missing some nuance or detail about how this "feature" operates?

Comment: Thing is that questions presume they are always deleted by votes, answers has to account for review deletes.

Comment: You sure you're not looking at questions where the owner was merged / deleted / etc.

Comment: @Shog9 How can I tell? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53946753/2191572

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about then. Yeah, that's the normal display - the thing you're referring to with answers shown as "deleted by owner" is an optimization - don't have to bother looking up the user if it's the same as the author.

Comment: @Shog9 So is my question better suited as a `feature-request`?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say so - not sure if there's a clear win here for questions.

Comment: A question could only be deleted by a single user if the user either a) is the owner or b) has a diamond. Not sure how much concern there can be about username being non-unique.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I guess this is just a desire for consistency. If someone is not familiar with those two rules or if a third rule is added in the future then we're back to square one of "Why is the username listed instead of owner." Please [Don't Make me Think](https://www.amazon.com/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758)

Comment: Fair enough, @MonkeyZeus.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I don't think this is that big of a deal...